# how to solve java file can't recognize its xml file

Tags: java, android-studio

when I start a new activity  in android studio java can't recognize the xml file.

for instance, the java file: *register.java*

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_register)
```

error shown on activity_register , which said that JVM can't find its corresponding file 
I tried to produce java file and xml file separately, but had no luck
the name of xml file is correct, i think.

Please help me how to solve the problem,
thanks!

Comment: please be much more precices and format your question nicely. The better the question, the better the answer.

Comment: em.I think my description in question is pretty precise , and dunno know what info you want ?

Comment: reproduceability. i have no information whatsoever about your project structure. code. we have almost none of your source. the error. we have a vague description "java can't recognize the xml file" .. what is this, "java"? Tell us more!

Comment: Try clearing the cache and restart.

Comment: You may want to read [ask].

Comment: make sure activity_register.xml exists in your layout folder and try to "clean", "rebuild", "invalidate cache and restart"

Answer (score 0):

File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... -> Select Invalidate and Restart